# Swagger/ReDoc overriding Razor pages

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, swagger, asp.net-core-3.1, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm trying to build a Razor pages site with an included API, using .Net Core 3.1. Once implementing Swashbuckle/Swagger/ReDoc, my home/root page no longer works (404) although the ReDoc generated page does. Everytime I run the project, it loads up `localhost:{port}/index.html` rather than the index.cshtml Razor page.

Is there a way to change this behavior so that my root url is pointed to the Razor index file?

Here is what I am doing in my Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    
    //Misc other config
    
    services.AddControllers();

    services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
        {
            Title = "API Documentation",
            Version = "v1",
            Description = File.ReadAllText($"{AppContext.BaseDirectory}\\wwwroot\\DocumentationMarkdown.txt")

        });
        var xmlFile = $"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}.xml";
        var xmlPath = Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, xmlFile);
        c.IncludeXmlComments(xmlPath, true);
    });
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseReDoc(c =>
    {
        c.SpecUrl("/swagger/v1/swagger.json");
        c.EnableUntrustedSpec();
        c.ScrollYOffset(10);
        c.HideHostname();
        c.HideDownloadButton();
        c.ExpandResponses("200,201");
        c.NoAutoAuth();
        c.PathInMiddlePanel();
        c.HideLoading();
        c.NativeScrollbars();
        c.SortPropsAlphabetically();
        c.DocumentTitle = "API Documentation";
    });
}
```

And my Pages structure is something like this:

```
Pages
    Shared
        _Layout.cshtml
    _ViewStart.cshtml
    Index.cshtml
    Index.cshtml.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out... Based on this post [Aspnet core 2.2 default route changed to "~/index.html" after installing Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54448639/aspnet-core-2-2-default-route-changed-to-index-html-after-installing-swashbu)

I added the RoutePrefix, which I had done before, but of course the issue was the browser cache. One hard reset later and I'm in business. Just a note too, the above works for .Net Core 3.1 as well as lower versions.